# Positioning img element using css

Tags: html, css, position, margin

Code :

```
html -> https://pastebin.com/zNekXPLQ 
css -> https://pastebin.com/tifEY0A4
```

I want to make the instagram button 30px from the right and 30 px from the top. But when using margin-right: 30px;, nothing happens, and when using right: 30px;, it plain disappears. Can someone please explain when and how to use margin-right ect and right, left, top, bottom attributes if at all? I'm new to html/css and positioning elements seems to be the hardest bottleneck to pass.

Comment: You have position fixed on the topbar

Answer (score 0):

You have position:fixed on .topbar but there is no width to it. Set a width to inherit from container, and then set position for the button, i recommend adding the class to the a tag instead of the img tag

**Html:**

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/majic.photography/" target="_blank" class = "instagrambutton">
     <img src="instagram-logo-white.png" alt="majic.photography" />
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.topbar {
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;
}

.instagrambutton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    top:30px;
    right:30px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The others have provided the answers you need. My answer is not the answer you really want right now, but I am providing it because you are new to HTML and CSS.

Can I strongly recommend moving away from Absolute positioning it becomes damn near impossible to manage when you start thinking about cross-browser compatibility and now cross device compatibility (30px on a desktop is far different from 30px on a mobile screen). When I was new to software development I used absolute positioning a lot and having to almost write a new CSS script for each browser/device with custom styles (maybe slightly exaggerated).

Having been out of the field and then coming back in in the last year or so, I strongly recommend learning and using [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) to style your web page.